# Does one's "lawyer license" need to be regularly renewed?

Tags: united-states, california, lawyer, bar-association

Say that Bob passes the bar exam. Then he goes to a mountain and becomes a hermit for X years. When he comes back, is he still allowed to be a lawyer? Or does his "law license" require regular renewal? And does that renewal require re-passing some exam, or is it just nominal (like renewing a driver's license)?

Answer (score 1):

In most states, you have to pay an annual or biannual registration fee, complete a certain number of continuing education classes each registration cycle, and fill out a form affirming that your contact information is up to date.

An attorney usually also has to make certain other representations in the registration process (e.g. no child support debts outstanding, you haven't been disciplined or charged criminally in any jurisdictions for professional misconduct or a crime, you do or do not have malpractice insurance in force, how many hours of pro bono work did you do, you do or do not have a trust account in place, you are or are not retired). Sometimes there are optional surveys that you may complete as well (e.g. regarding salaries and hours worked and type of practice and disability status).

If you fail to comply with these registration requirements after receiving warnings to do so, your license to practice law is suspended. The conditions upon which your license can be reinstated and the process for doing so varies from state to state.

Exceptions to the usual rules often exist if you primarily practice law in another state, you are on "inactive status" for some reason, or you are retired.

Generally speaking, to keep your license current, you don't have to take new exams regarding the practice of law or legal ethics, and you generally don't have to complete the comprehensive background check called character and fitness review that is necessary to be admitted to the practice of law in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Yes.

In order to practise as a solicitor<sup>1</sup> they must renew their eligibility every year and meet the requirements at [section 1(c)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1974/47/section/1?timeline=false), Solicitors Act 1974:

> (1) No person shall be qualified to act as a solicitor unless—
>
> - (a) he has been admitted as a solicitor, and
> - (b) his name is on the roll, and
> - (c) **he has in force a certificate** issued by the Society in accordance with the provisions of this Part authorising him to practise as a solicitor (in this Act referred to as a “practising certificate”).

The Practicing Certificate is renewed annually, and for [2022-2023 costs £286](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/topics/news-articles/pc-fees-2022-2023).

---

<sup>1</sup>For clarity, ["solicitor" is a regulated term](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1974/47/section/20?timeline=false), unlike "Lawyer" and:

> Anyone can call themselves a lawyer, regardless of whether they have any professional legal qualifications or not. [Source](https://www.sra.org.uk/consumers/choosing/legal-jargon-explained/#:%7E:text=Anyone%20can%20call%20themselves%20a,professional%20legal%20qualifications%20or%20not.)

Comment: Although tagged USA and California, I have answered in line with: *we expect and encourage answers dealing with other jurisdictions ... please tag your answer using the tag markdown: [tag: some-tag]*". From the [Help centre](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)